# Does somebody know a form select skinning plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-6

I need a jQuery plugin for skinning the form select tag. Currently I'm using the Uniform plugin but it degrades on IE6. Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For form elements skinning I use [jqTransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/)

Comment: Yes I use it too but this project I can't use it unfortunately. Reasons don't know, they don't want me to use it. That's why I'm using Uniform but i does not render on IE6

Answer (score 1):

Do you know jQuery UI? Have a look at this:

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/
- http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 0):

one i used [this](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) and i liked it very much - its a plugin for a multiselect (don't know if you need a multi- or a single select) (maybe its possible to use this for single selects, i havn't tried that)

**EDIT:** [this](http://jonathan.tang.name/code/jquery_combobox) is for a single select-dropdown, but it's not as beautiful as the other one i mentioned